# Custom image attribute not taking value javascript (except in IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, custom-attribute

I have stumbled across a strange thing whilst working with Javascript and the `Image` object. I do not fully know the standard for adding custom attributes to pre existing object types such as `Image` as I can't seem to find the right doccumentation on it.
Here is my code:

```
test2 = 2;
test = new Image();
alert(test + " " + test2);
test2.x = 3;
test.x = 3;
alert(test.x + " " + test2.x);
```

What I expect to happen is the first `alert()` to display

[object HTMLImageElement] 2
Which it does display. Then I expect the second `alert()` to display

> 3 undefined

This also displays like this but only in Internet Explorer.
It displays this

> 0 undefined

in all other browsers that I have tested: Google Chrome(latest stable), Mozilla Firefox(latest stable)
I only tested it on IE 9 and none of the earlier versions

I don't understand why this only works in IE and am I using it correctly?
Thanks in advance, Kyle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to set property `x` of an image, is because the image being an instance of `HTMLImageElement`, already has an `x` and `y` property, which are read-only. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Properties).